# How to target specific columns with DT's SearchPanes extension

Tags: r, dt

I want to implement `DT`'s `SearchPanes` extension while explicitly including/excluding specific fields but am not sure how to accomplish it. I want all of the fields to show, but only select fields to be included in the SearchPanes interface.

In the reproducible example below (which is essentially from the documentation), how would I select just `island`, `sex`, and `year` for inclusion in `SearchPanes`?

I've tried different settings with `searchPanes` and the `targets` arguments, but I do not understand how to use these and I don't yet follow the JS documentation very well. Any guidance on how these work and how to select columns for inclusion would be much appreciated.

```r
library(DT)
library(palmerpenguins)
```

```r
datatable(
  penguins,
  options = list(dom = 'Pfrtip', columnDefs = list(list(
    searchPanes = list(show = FALSE), targets = 1:4
  ))),
  extensions = c('Select', 'SearchPanes'),
  selection = 'none'
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a better way but this works:

```r
datatable(
  penguins,
  options = list(
    dom = 'Pfrtip', 
    columnDefs = list(
      list(
        searchPanes = list(show = FALSE), targets = c(1, 3:6)
      ),
      list(
        searchPanes = list(show = TRUE), targets = c(2, 7:9)
      )
    )
  ),
  extensions = c('Select', 'SearchPanes'),
  selection = 'none'
)
```

The `searchPanes` argument `show` can be set to `TRUE` or `FALSE` and the state is directed to specific target columns defined in the `targets` argument.

On one line, I set `show=FALSE` and defined all of the columns that I did not want showing. Then on the following line, I set `showTRUE` and defined the columns that I want showing. I found that if I set a column to `show=FALSE` and in the next line set it to `show=TRUE` it remains unshown.

The DataTables JS library [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/#searchpanes) was helpful, but took a bit to understand. The section on [`columns.searchPanes.show`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.searchPanes.show) contained the answer. Each `searchPanes` statement has some arguments and a set of targets. As follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        dom: 'Plfrtip',
        columnDefs: [
            {
                searchPanes: {
                    show: true
                },
                targets: [0]
            },
            {
                searchPanes: {
                    show: false
                },
                targets: [2]
            }
        ]
    });
});
```